# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$SQLGetLogs = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE user=$username");
while($getInfo = $SQLGetLogs -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $user = $getInfo['user'];
    $IP = $getInfo['ip'];
}
```

I have this code here where I am trying to pull user logs from a database according to the users name. I am having some trouble which I think might be due to the fetch, however can't seem to get around it. If I change the username variable to just a set username e.g. $user=billy, then it will correctly pull the query for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try putting it inside quotes like `WHERE user='$username' "` or `WHERE user='" . $username . "' "`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my MySQL INSERT statement returning an error? PDOException SQLSTATE\[42000\]:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672870/why-is-my-mysql-insert-statement-returning-an-error-pdoexception-sqlstate42000)

Comment: Your query is generating an (uncaught) error therefore `$SQLGetLogs` is `false`. See the duplicate question for more details.